# Начально-краевая задача для уравнения теплопроводности

Tags: математика

Мне нужно решить начально-краевую задачу для уравнения теплопроводности с запаздыванием по времени. А именно нужно доказать теорему существования и единственности решения. Нет ли ни у кого подобных примеров или литературы. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Краевых задач три. Для какой из вам нужно решение?

Answer (score 2):

Нужно рассмотреть решение от обратного, т.е. предположим, что есть 2 решения - `u1` и `u2`.

Тогда разность `u1` и `u2` будет удволетворять:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`v(x, t) ≡ 0` будет являться решением этой задачи. Остается доказать, что других решений нет.

1. Домножим обе части на `v(x,t)` и проинтегрируем по `x` от `0` до `l`
2. Применим интегрирование по частям. В силу краевых условий подстановка обратится в ноль:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так как

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То из результата интегрирования (предыдущая вставка) следует, что `z(t)` - не положительна:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Значит, `z(t)` - невозрастающая функция и `z(t) <= z(0)` при `t >= 0`.

Из начального условия получаем:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С учетом неотрицательности `z(t)` выполняется неравенство `0<=z(t)<=0`, что значит что `z(t) ≡ 0`.

Так как подинтегральная функция неотрицательна, то `v(x, t) = 0`. А в силу непрерывности `v(x,t)` - `v(x, t) ≡ 0`

А вообще, данное доказательство представлено практически во всех учебниках по мат.физике

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Но проблема в том, что это доказательство для уравнения без запаздывания.